# Does prior distribution matter in classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Currently I get a classification problem with two classes. what I want to do is that given a bunch of candidates, find out who will more likely to be the class 1. The problem is that class 1 is very rare (around 1%), which I guess makes my prediction quite inaccurate.
For training the dataset, can I sample half class 1 and half class 0? This will change the prior distribution, but I don't know whether the prior distribution affects the classification results?

Comment: Check these: http://florianhartl.com/thoughts-on-machine-learning-dealing-with-skewed-classes.html or http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/10691/InTech-Data_mining_with_skewed_data.pdf

Comment: This mostly depends on which classification method you are using. It also sounds as if you are talking of "balanced" vs "unbalanced" dataset, rather than about "prior distribution", which is a different thing.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, a very imbalanced dataset can cause problems in classification. Because by defaulting to the majority class 0, you can get your error rate already very low.

There are some workarounds that may or may not work for your particular problem, such as giving equal weight to the two classes (thus weighting instances from the rare class stronger), oversampling the rare class (i.e. learning each instance multiple times), producing slight variations of the rare objects to restore balance etc. SMOTE and so on.

You really should to grab some **classification or machine learning book**, and check the index for "imbalanced classification" or "unbalanced classification". If the book is any good, it *will* discuss this problem. (I just assume you did not know the term that they use.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're forced to pick exactly one from a group, then the prior distribution over classes won't matter because it will be constant for all members of that group. If you must look at each in turn and make an independent decision as to whether they're class one or class two, the prior will potentially change the decision, depending on which method you choose to do the classification. I would suggest you get hold of as many examples of the rare class as possible, but beware that feeding a 50-50 split to a classifier as training blindly may make it implicitly fit a model that assumes this is the distribution at test time.

Answer (score 0):

Sampling your two classes evenly doesn't change assumed priors unless your classification algorithm computes (and uses) priors based on the training data.  You stated that your problem is "given a bunch of candidates, find out who will more likely to be the class 1". I read this to mean that you want to determine which observation is most likely to belong to class 1.  To do this, you want to pick the observation $x_i$ that maximizes $p(c_1|x_i)$. Using Bayes' theorem, this becomes:

$$
p(c_1|x_i)=\frac{p(x_i|c_1)p(c_1)}{p(x_i)}
$$

You can ignore $p(c_1)$ in the equation above since it is a constant.  However, computing the denominator will still involve using prior probabilities.  Since your problem is really more of a target detection problem than a classification problem, an alternate approach for detecting low probability targets is to take the likelihood ratio of the two classes:

$$
\Lambda=\frac{p(x_i|c_1)}{p(x_i|c_0)}
$$

To pick which of your candidates is most likely to belong to class 1, pick the one with the highest value of $\Lambda$.  If your two classes are described by multivariate Gaussian distributions, you can replace $\Lambda$ with its natural logarithm, resulting in a simpler quadratic detector.  If you further assume that the target and background have the same covariance matrices, this results in a linear discriminant (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider Bayesian utility theory to re-weight the costs of different kinds of error to get away from the problem of the priors dominating the decision.

Let A be the 99% prior probability class, B be the 1% class.

If we just say that all errors incur the same cost (negative utility), then 
it's possible that the optimal decision approach is to always declare "A".  Many
classification algorithms (implicitly) assume this.

If instead, we declare that the cost of declaring "B" when, in fact, the instance
was "A" is much bigger than the cost of the opposite error, then the decision logic
becomes, in a sense, more sensitive to slighter differences in the features.

This kind of situation frequently comes up in fault detection -- faults in the monitored
system will be rare, but you want to be sure that if we see any data that points to 
an error condition, action needs to be taken (even if it is just reviewing the data).